# IRA after tax withdrawal taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira

I made after tax contributions to a IRA 35+ years ago ($2000.00). Should that money (2000.00) come out tax free? If so how?
Thanks

Comment: Wow, 35+ years ago works out to 1980 tax year or earlier. While IRAs were established in 1974, they didn't become popular till the 1980s, and so you must have been one of the very early participants.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it should come out tax free. However you should have reported it  to the IRS at the time (currently it is done on form 8606). If you haven't done it, the IRS may disagree with you on that and require taxes.

If you have proper documentation of the contribution, then when you withdraw from your IRA - you use that same form 8606 to calculate the non-taxable portion. Note that you cannot just take $2K out of the 1099-R, the non-taxable portion will be prorated through all of your IRA withdrawals.

Also, keep in mind that only the actual after tax portion will be tax-free, the gains will be taxable. I.e.: if you deposited $2K after tax (and nothing else), and they have now grown to $100K - you will only have 2% of your distribution tax free (2k/100K * distributed amount).